# How to open an info window with split screen google map and street view?

Tags: google-maps-markers, infowindow, google-street-view

So I have a functioning code ([example here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service)) to create a split screen of half google map Hybrid view and then when you click somewhere on that map (left side) then (right side) opens street view for that location.

I want to have a marker on the hybrid map side that when clicked on opens an info window on that side and then the street view for that location on the right side of the screen. But I can't seem to figure out how to code in that marker to open as an info window/bubble on the left side map?

Here's the code currently (including the mistake I've made as it doesn't work):

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(42.315126 , -72.63455);
var DoYouFeel = new google.maps.LatLng(42.315148 , -72.634429)
var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

var panorama;

function initialize() {

  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'));

  // Set up the map
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    streetViewControl: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  //Set up the markers
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: DoYouFeel,
  });
marker.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  bubble = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<div id="mydiv"><br><embed src="Do You Feel....mov" width="720" height="576" align="center"><br><br></div>'

        })
        bubble.open(map, marker);
});

  // getPanoramaByLocation will return the nearest pano when the
  // given radius is 50 meters or less.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      sv.getPanoramaByLocation(event.latLng, 50, processSVData);
  });
}

function processSVData(data, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: data.location.latLng,
      map: map,
      title: data.location.description
    });

    panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
    panorama.setPov({
      heading: 270,
      pitch: 0
    });
    panorama.setVisible(true);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

      var markerPanoID = data.location.pano;
      // Set the Pano to use the passed panoID
      panorama.setPano(markerPanoID);
      panorama.setPov({
        heading: 270,
        pitch: 0
      });
      panorama.setVisible(true);
    });
  } else {
    alert('Street View data not found for this location.');
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Comment: oh, I think the issue was I was missing "var map;" from the topas now it works!